# How to change the date format in comment field that has date along with comments

Tags: sql

I am trying to change the date format in Comment field in SQL, My comments field display data some thing like this 'shaik4, jabeen4 7/2/2019 10:11:41 AM',
Comments can be longer until 2000 characters followed by date , i want my date to be in 07/02/2019 format

Comment: This is not something best done in SQL.  If you want a date, then you should store it in a column not in a comment string.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: A better idea would be to store the date in a separate column to begin with. And probably makes sense to store the username separately too

Answer (score 1):

```
select Convert(VARCHAR(23), Cast(right(Comments, 23) as Datetime), 106) as Date
FROM *Table*
```

Might be the trick.

First we get the right side of the comments field to grab the date and time, then we cast it to a datetime value, then we convert our datetime to the appropriate format.

You will need to replace the 23 in comments with the appropriate amount of cells away. So 05/05/2019 11:21:00.000 would be 23.  Then the 106 needs to be replaced with the correctly formatted conversion.  The convert part should be easy to look up with some external resources.

If this doesn't do the trick, share more info on your database type and hopefully we can work through this together. Thanks